# Does Push notification going to display if loc-key missing in the payload

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, payload

What is going to happen in live apps when remote notification sends with 
 the payload with Empty loc-key or Wrong loc-key.

Does push notification appear to the user with a wrong message (key itself) or it won't show to the user at all?

**Scenario 1:**

***Payload***:

```
{"aps":{"alert":{"loc-key":"TEXTKEY","loc-args":[]}}}
```

localizable.strings doesn't contain the text for TEXTKEY

**Scenario 2:**

***Payload***:

```
{"aps":{"alert":{"loc-key":"","loc-args":[]}}}
```

Comment: Yes push appear with TEXTKEY text.

Answer (score 0):

`loc-key`- A key to an alert-message string in a `Localizable.strings` file for the current localization (which is set by the user’s language preference). The `loc-key` and `loc-args` keys define the message content of the notification. When present, the local system searches the app’s `Localizable.strings` files for a key string matching the value in `loc-key`. It then uses the corresponding value from the strings file as the basis for the message text, replacing any placeholder values with the strings specified by the `loc-args` key. If corresponding values is not find in `Localizable.strings` files then it display the `loc-key` as it is.
for further information check out [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).

Comment: How this will be handled in different versions of the same app. ex: if TEXTKEY="text 1" in version 1. And in version 2 for some reasons if we change the loc-key to UPDTEXTKEY="text1".

Comment: @BuddySuri what did you mean by different versions?

Comment: I mean the app versions. if the user didn't upgrade to latest version of the app.

Comment: Make sure for versioning of your APNS API, otherwise you can go with Force update.